# WordPress Gutenberg Custom Block Getting All Posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to create a custom block but I need some assistance.

I'm attempting to setup a `<select>` in the editor that lists all the posts. I'm not very experienced at the api yet but after reading the docs, it seems that the below line should work to get the posts.

```
wp.api.collections.Posts().fetch()
```

The problem is, however, I'm getting a nice error of:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collections' of undefined

How can I get a list of all the posts for selection within the editor, or is it just outside the realm of possibility?

Comment: Technically it should work if you add `wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' );` to the `php` file with the same name as your gutenberg custom block, however, I can't get it to work either, there's a `backbone` error about reading `apply` of `undefined`. All solutions I've seen are the same as the answer you've gotten. I'm not sure what's going on with the wordpress documentation.

Comment: If you want to see posts just within the editor component, and not in the rendered output, you can use `getEntityRecords` , see the official Posts block component: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/latest-posts unfortunately though their render component is written in PHP, leaving those of us that want to write block components in JSX as the docs recommend, in the dark

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead

```
const { apiFetch } = wp;
apiFetch({ path: "/wp/v2/posts" }).then(posts => {
  console.log(posts);
});
```